# Using SSL support for Java clients & WebSphere MQ

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to IBM MQ using a Java client.I have setup the necessary keydatabase,keystore and truststore files following the below tutorial.

> https://qadeer786.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/using-ssl-support-for-java-clients-websphere-mq/

When I run the Java client it gives me the following error.

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2397'.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:249)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:450)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:487)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:97)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:194)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:868)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:816)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:758)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:200)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:682)
    at esb.wso2.org.client.MQConnectionBuilder.<init>(MQConnectionBuilder.java:52)
    at esb.wso2.org.client.MQConnectionBuilder.getInstance(MQConnectionBuilder.java:60)
    at esb.wso2.org.client.MQProducer.<init>(MQProducer.java:20)
    at esb.wso2.org.client.MQClient.main(MQClient.java:7)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host '127.0.0.1(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[Remote host closed connection during handshake],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]],3=127.0.0.1(1414),5=RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2282)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1294)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:560)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.MQCONNX_j(MQSESSION.java:916)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:235)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[Remote host closed connection during handshake],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1329)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:863)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:409)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:305)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1730)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$6.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1298)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$6.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1290)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1290)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    ... 30 more
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2397'.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:249)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:450)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:487)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:97)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:194)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:868)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:816)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:758)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:200)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:682)
    at esb.wso2.org.client.MQConnectionBuilder.getQueueManager(MQConnectionBuilder.java:68)
    at esb.wso2.org.client.MQProducer.<init>(MQProducer.java:22)
    at esb.wso2.org.client.MQClient.main(MQClient.java:7)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host '127.0.0.1(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[Remote host closed connection during handshake],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]],3=127.0.0.1(1414),5=RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2282)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1294)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:376)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:560)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.MQCONNX_j(MQSESSION.java:916)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:235)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[Remote host closed connection during handshake],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:1414 (localhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1329)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:863)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:409)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:305)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:146)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1730)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$6.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1298)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$6.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1290)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1290)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    ... 29 more
```

Below you get the queue manager (qmanager) log file.

```
 2017-06-24 11:31:11 - Process(25266.5) User(root) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(hasitha-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(qmanager)

AMQ9660: SSL key repository: password stash file absent or unusable.

EXPLANATION:

The SSL key repository cannot be used because MQ cannot obtain a password to access
 it. Reasons giving rise to this error include: 

(a) the key database file and password stash file are not present in the
      location configured for the key repository, 

(b) the key database file exists in the correct place but that no password
      stash file has been created for it, 

(c) the files are present in the correct place but the userid under which MQ is
      running does not have permission to read them, 

(d) one or both of the files are corrupt. 


The channel is '????'; in some cases its name cannot be determined and so is
shown as '????'. The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Ensure that the key repository variable is set to where the key database file
is. Ensure that a password stash file has been associated with the key database
file in the same directory, and that the userid under which MQ is running has
read access to both files. If both are already present and readable in the
correct place, delete and recreate them. Restart the channel.
----- amqccisa.c : 6283 -------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-24 11:31:11 - Process(25266.5) User(root) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(hasitha-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(qmanager)

AMQ9999: Channel '????' to host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 25266 for channel '????' ended
abnormally. The host name is 'localhost (127.0.0.1)'; in some cases the host
name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide.
----- amqrmrsa.c : 930 --------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-24 11:33:54 - Process(25266.6) User(root) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(hasitha-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(qmanager)

AMQ9660: SSL key repository: password stash file absent or unusable.

EXPLANATION:
The SSL key repository cannot be used because MQ cannot obtain a password to
access it. Reasons giving rise to this error include: 
(a) the key database file and password stash file are not present in the
  location configured for the key repository, 
(b) the key database file exists in the correct place but that no password
  stash file has been created for it, 
(c) the files are present in the correct place but the userid under which MQ is
  running does not have permission to read them, 
(d) one or both of the files are corrupt. 

The channel is '????'; in some cases its name cannot be determined and so is
shown as '????'. The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Ensure that the key repository variable is set to where the key database file
is. Ensure that a password stash file has been associated with the key database
file in the same directory, and that the userid under which MQ is running has
read access to both files. If both are already present and readable in the
correct place, delete and recreate them. Restart the channel.
----- amqccisa.c : 6283 -------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-24 11:33:54 - Process(25266.6) User(root) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(hasitha-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(qmanager)

AMQ9999: Channel '????' to host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 25266 for channel '????' ended
abnormally. The host name is 'localhost (127.0.0.1)'; in some cases the host
name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide.
----- amqrmrsa.c : 930 --------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-24 11:33:55 - Process(25266.7) User(root) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(hasitha-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(qmanager)

AMQ9660: SSL key repository: password stash file absent or unusable.

EXPLANATION:
The SSL key repository cannot be used because MQ cannot obtain a password to
access it. Reasons giving rise to this error include: 
(a) the key database file and password stash file are not present in the
  location configured for the key repository, 
(b) the key database file exists in the correct place but that no password
  stash file has been created for it, 
(c) the files are present in the correct place but the userid under which MQ is
  running does not have permission to read them, 
(d) one or both of the files are corrupt. 

The channel is '????'; in some cases its name cannot be determined and so is
shown as '????'. The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Ensure that the key repository variable is set to where the key database file
is. Ensure that a password stash file has been associated with the key database
file in the same directory, and that the userid under which MQ is running has
read access to both files. If both are already present and readable in the
correct place, delete and recreate them. Restart the channel.
----- amqccisa.c : 6283 -------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-24 11:33:55 - Process(25266.7) User(root) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(hasitha-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(8.0.0.4) QMgr(qmanager)

AMQ9999: Channel '????' to host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 25266 for channel '????' ended
abnormally. The host name is 'localhost (127.0.0.1)'; in some cases the host
name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide.
----- amqrmrsa.c : 930 --------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this.I have the user group mqm and both root and $USER(hasitha) are users of that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you followed appears to be on Windows, but from your final comment I think you are on a Unix system.

You need to check the ownership of the queue manager's key database file.

Your queue manager error log hints at this when it says:-

```
(c) the files are present in the correct place but the userid under which MQ is
      running does not have permission to read them,
```

Go into the directory which contains the queue manager key database file, C:\temp\ssldemo1\ in the tutorial, and change the ownership of the four files in there to mqm with the following command:-

```
chown mqm TEST.QM1.*
```

Comment: Still the same error pops up.I've added root and $USER(hasitha) to the user group mqm and I am running  MQ explorer as root.I think I need to add keydatabase and password stash file to the directory /var/mqm/qmgrs/qmanager/ssl (My queue manager name is qmanager). But from user hasitha I can't open the ssl folder as the warning message states that I have not permission to write the file ssl(Eventhough I've added the user hasitha to mqm).So I used nautilus /var/mqm/qmgrs/qmanager/ssl and added the files.Is this a correct procedure?

Comment: Another problem is that the ikeyman doesn't start when I start the MQExplorer from root but only in $USER(hasitha). Can you provide me the correct way of adding ssl to the IBM MQ 8.0.I followed http://sadockobeth.blogspot.com/2014/03/how-to-install-ibm-websphere-mq-75-on.html this when installing IBM MQ for the first time.

Comment: @Hussey123 post the output of the following command run as the mqm user: `ls -l /var/mqm/qmgrs/qmanager/ssl`

Comment: @Hussey123 I also noted from the queue manager error log that you started the queue manager as `root`. On unix you should start it as the `mqm` user.

Comment: If you're running the queue manager as `root` then changing the ownership of the files to `mqm` won't have helped. The files need to be owned by the user that runs the queue manager. Run the queue manager as `mqm` as @JoshMc suggests.

Comment: @JoshMc Morag I've added the key and stash file with mqm ownership to the ../qmanager/ssl folder and it worked.Thanks for the help.